# Canvas - good rendering practices?

Tags: java, rendering

I've been using the Canvas a lot lately for little Java games and i've noticed a lot of strange things can happen. For example, earlier today I created a little game in which the objective is to shoot enemy ships and get points. The game draws tiny 32x32 images on the screen (sometimes slightly bigger) and for a reason I am oblivious to, the game renders oddly.

For example, my ship has a health bar above it's head:

[image]

As you can see by the image, the textures are really small. Despite this, the game lags and sometimes things render incorrectly like this for example:

[image]

If you look closely at the top of the health bar, you can see that it's been shifted upwards slightly, it puzzles me how his happens as all of my rendering is buffered.

My rendering code:

```
public void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)bs.getDrawGraphics();
    toDrawG.setColor(new Color(0x222222));
    toDrawG.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    draw((Graphics2D)toDrawG);
    g.drawImage(toDraw, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g){
    if(Settings.planets){
    renderer.renderPlanets();
    }
    if(level != null){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < level.entityList.size(); i++){
        if(level.entityList.get(i) != null){
        level.entityList.get(i).render(renderer);
        }
        }
    }
    renderer.overlayString("Space Game", 20, 20, 24, 0xFFFFFF);
    renderer.overlayString(VERSION, 20, 50, 24, 0xFFFFFF);
    renderer.overlayString("FPS: " + renderer.fps, 20, 70, 24, 0xFFFFFF);
    renderer.overlayString("Ships spawned: " + level.shipsSpawned, 20, 90, 24,     0xFFFFFF);
    renderer.overlayString("Time Survived: " + level.time / 100 + "s", 20, 110,     24, 0xFFFFFF);
    renderer.overlayString("Physics FPS: " + fps, 20, 130, 24, 0xFFFFFF);

    if(currentGui != null){
        currentGui.render(renderer);
    }else{
        map.drawMinimap(SpaceGame.WIDTH-Minimap.WIDTH-20, SpaceGame.HEIGHT-    Minimap.HEIGHT-30);
    }

}
```

And my "Render.class" if you need to study it:

```
package com.maestrum;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ConvolveOp;
import java.awt.image.Kernel;
import java.util.Random;

public class Render implements Runnable{

public Graphics2D g2d;

public double xScroll,yScroll;

public int frames;
public int fps;
public long lastTime;

public int[] pSequence = new int[40];   
public SpaceGame game;

public Entity trackedEntity;

public Random rand;

public Render(SpaceGame game, Graphics2D g){
    this.game = game;
    this.g2d = g;
    this.rand = new Random();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 40; i++){
        pSequence[i] = rand.nextInt(15) + 1;
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {     
    renderLoop();
}

public void renderLoop(){
    while(true){
        game.render();
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime >= 1000){
            fps = frames;
            frames = 0;
            lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        frames++;
    }
}

public void renderPlanets(){
    overlayImage(ImageHandler.background, 0, 0, 1.5);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 20; i++){
        overlayImage(ImageHandler.planets[pSequence[i]/4][pSequence[i]%4], i * 400 - xScroll/pSequence[i], i * pSequence[i]*40 - yScroll/pSequence[i]*2, pSequence[i]);
    }
}

private class PlanetRenderer {



}

public void overlayString(String s, double x, double y, int fontSize, int colour){
    drawString(s, x+xScroll, y+yScroll, fontSize, colour);
}

public void overlayRectangle(double x, double y, int xs, int ys, int colour){
    drawRectangle(x+xScroll, y+yScroll, xs, ys, colour);
}

public void overlayBlurred(BufferedImage img, double x, double y, double scale){
    drawImageBlurred(img, x+xScroll, y+yScroll, scale);
}

public void overlayImage(BufferedImage img, double x, double y, double scale){
    drawImage(img, x+xScroll, y+yScroll, scale);
}

public BufferedImage execute(BufferedImage img) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    float weight = 1.0f/2.0f;

    float [] elements = {weight, weight, weight, weight, weight, weight, weight, weight, weight};

    Kernel k = new Kernel (3,3,elements);
    ConvolveOp op = new ConvolveOp(k);

    BufferedImage dest = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), img.getType());

    op.filter(img, dest);
    return dest;
}

public void drawImageBlurred(BufferedImage img, double x, double y, double scale){
    x -= xScroll;
    y -= yScroll;
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage((int)(img.getWidth()*scale), (int)(img.getHeight()*scale), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, (int)(img.getWidth()*scale), (int)(img.getHeight()*scale), null);
    execute(image);
    g2d.drawImage(image, (int)x, (int)y, null);
    g.dispose();
}

public void drawString(String s, Vector2D pos, int fontSize, int colour){
    drawString(s, pos.x, pos.y, fontSize, colour);
}

public void drawString(String s, double x, double y, int fontSize, int colour){
    if(s == null){
        return;
    }
    x -= xScroll;
    y -= yScroll;
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(s.length()*fontSize+1, fontSize*2, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(new Color(colour));
    g.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, fontSize));
    g.drawString(s, 0, img.getHeight()/2);
    g2d.drawImage(img, (int)x, (int)y, null);
    g.dispose();
}

public void drawImage(BufferedImage img, Vector2D pos, double scale){
    drawImage(img, pos.x, pos.y, scale);
}

public void drawLine(Vector2D v1, Vector2D v2, int colour, int width){
    drawLine(v1.x, v1.y, v2.x, v2.y, colour, width);
}

public void drawLine(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, int colour, int lWidth){
    x1 -= xScroll;
    y1 -= yScroll;
    x2 -= xScroll;
    y2 -= yScroll;
    g2d.setColor(new Color(colour));
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(lWidth));
    g2d.drawLine((int)x1, (int)y1, (int)x2, (int)y2);
}

public void drawImage(BufferedImage img, double x, double y, double scale){
    x -= xScroll;
    y -= yScroll;
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage((int)(img.getWidth()*scale), (int)(img.getHeight()*scale), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, (int)(img.getWidth()*scale), (int)(img.getHeight()*scale), null);
    g2d.drawImage(image, (int)x, (int)y, null);
    g.dispose();
}

public void drawRectangle(Vector2D pos, int xs, int ys, int colour){
    drawRectangle(pos.x, pos.y, xs, ys, colour);
}

public void drawRectangle(double x, double y, int xs, int ys, int colour){
    if(xs <= 0){
        return;
    }
    x -= xScroll;
    y -= yScroll;
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(xs, ys, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(new Color(colour));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, xs, ys);
    g2d.drawImage(image, (int)x, (int)y, null);
    g.dispose();
}

public void drawImageRotated(BufferedImage img, Vector2D pos, double scale, double angle) {
    drawImageRotated(img, pos.x, pos.y, scale, angle);
}

 public void drawImageRotated(BufferedImage img, double x, double y, double scale, double angle) {
        x -= xScroll;
        y -= yScroll;  
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage((int)(img.getWidth() * 1.5D), (int)(img.getHeight() * 1.5D), 2);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), image.getWidth() / 2, image.getHeight() / 2);
        g.drawImage(img, image.getWidth() / 2 - img.getWidth() / 2, image.getHeight() / 2 - image.getHeight() / 2, null);
        g2d.drawImage(image, (int)(x-image.getWidth()*scale/2), (int)(y-image.getHeight()*scale/2), (int)(image.getWidth()*scale), (int)(image.getHeight()*scale), null);
        g.dispose();      
 }
```

}

As you can see in the rendering class, the render process is done as many times a second as possible. This is to give the game the highest possible FPS. If you missed the point of what I'm asking; What good practices should I take into account when rendering stuff using Java? And, what could possibly be causing the space ships health bar to render like so?

NOTE: take a look at this video, I ran that program and got 80FPS with 50000 particles, however with my rendering code (which is obviously of a much lower quality) I can render only a mere 100 or so particles, before things start messing up.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6M3Ze4Eu87Y

This is my tick() function, it gets called every game tick (10ms)

```
public void tick(){
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime >= 1000){
        fps = frames;
        frames = 0;
        lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    frames++;
    if(renderer.trackedEntity != null){
        renderer.xScroll = renderer.trackedEntity.pos.x-SpaceGame.WIDTH/2;
        renderer.yScroll = renderer.trackedEntity.pos.y-SpaceGame.HEIGHT/2;
    }
    if(level != null && !paused){
        level.tick();
    }
    if(currentGui != null && currentGui.pausesGame()){
        paused = true;
    }else{
        paused = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't mean to post this. I'm editing it now.

Comment: what does it mean 'oddly'? slowly? flickering?

Comment: I edited it, look at the two images.

Comment: how do you update `xScroll` and `yScroll`?

Comment: It's done in the gameLoop, i'll add it to the post.

Comment: @ShaunWild Please i have been searching for something similar ever since https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44188513/how-to-appropriately-draw-a-fuel-bar, how do i get a similar fuel bar like yours

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i think the answer by @mantrid should fix your problem. 
as far as performance goes ... there are some obvious "sins" in your code:

**Don't draw an image into an image to draw an image**

```
public void drawImage(BufferedImage img, double x, double y, double scale){
    x -= xScroll;
    y -= yScroll;
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage((int)(img.getWidth()*scale), (int)(img.getHeight()*scale), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, (int)(img.getWidth()*scale), (int)(img.getHeight()*scale), null);
    g2d.drawImage(image, (int)x, (int)y, null);
    g.dispose();
}
```

I don't see the point of this. Why not just do this:

```
public void drawImage(BufferedImage img, double x, double y, double scale){
    g2d.drawImage(img, (int)(x-xScroll), (int)(y-yScroll), (int)(img.getWidth()*scale), (int)(img.getHeight()*scale), null);
}
```

**AAAAAAAAAAAAA**

The next one actually burnt my eyes

```
public void drawRectangle(double x, double y, int xs, int ys, int colour){
    if(xs <= 0){
        return;
    }
    x -= xScroll;
    y -= yScroll;
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(xs, ys, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(new Color(colour));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, xs, ys);
    g2d.drawImage(image, (int)x, (int)y, null);
    g.dispose();
}
```

Why? This is so much simpler and quicker:

```
public void drawRectangle(double x, double y, int xs, int ys, int colour){
    if(xs <= 0)
        return;

    g2d.setColor(new Color(colour));
    g2d.fillRect((int)(x-xScroll), (int)(y-yScroll), xs, ys);
}
```

The same goes for the `drawImageRotated` and `drawString`. 
Just draw to the g2d buffer directly, what are you afraid of?

**drawImageBlurred**

First of all... you're doing it again! 
Second: You seem to be applying a convolve operation to an image on each frame, why not just do that operation once (e.g. at the start of the app, or even better yet, in an image editing program).

I don't mean this in a bad way at all, but you are clearly not very experienced with programming in general. I think you could take a look at processing (http://processing.org). I'm sort of biased here because i'm using it myself almost everyday. It is a great learning and prototyping environment written in java that should allow you to stop thinking about implementation details (like flipping buffers) and focus on what you really care for (make a game!).

Alright, hope what i said makes sense. Good luck with your coding! :)

Comment: Thank you for this feedback. I drew the image onto the image as I was worried about the Graphics transformations affecting one another, I know now how to use the AffineTransform to restore an old transformation to the Graphics object. And by the way, the x -= xScroll had to be there as the game is a side scroller. After fixing up all my code from it's hideous former state, my game still seems to experience lag but it's generally a lot nicer. Thank you :)

Comment: @kritzikratzi i have been looking for this ever since, please how can i draw the exact same bar

Answer (score 6):

The health bar might be shifted because when game lags, `xScroll` and `yScroll` are updated while components/overlays are still being rendered into backbuffer.
To fix that:

1) move game objects proportionally to amout of time elapsed from latest update to keep game speed always constant. add `delta` parameter to `level.tick()` and all game objects update method

2) put `level.tick()` and `game.render()` within the same loop sequence to ensure game objects are updated first:

```
currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
delta = currentTime - lastTime; 

if(level != null && !paused){
    level.tick(delta); // introduce delta here
    game.render();
}

lastTime = currentTime;
```

In general, consider these additional steps:

1) set `Component.setIgnoreRepaint(true)` to speed up rendering

2) optimize images for current display at the start

```
GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment
.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
.getDefaultScreenDevice()
.getDefaultConfiguration();
Image optimized = gc.createCompatibleImage(img.getWidth(),img.getHeight(),Transparency.BITMASK);
optimized.getGraphics().drawImage(unoptimized, 0, 0, null);
```

Comment: I have to disagree with putting them on the same loop; doing so causes my fps to drop to around 4, i believe this is caused by the fact that the renderer needs to wait for the all of the physics to update first.

Comment: Well. When I did do it like that, I got a ton of lag. The first response I got to the problem was to make them on their own independent threads, and that seemed to have made the game run a lot quicker.

Comment: No, i think seperating this is a good solution. However, this answer points out an important thing: If you have two seperate threads accessing the same objects, you should have some sort of synchronization! If your object calls renderer mehtods multiple times, and in the meantime the object is changed, you will get such inconsistencies.

Comment: i completely disagree with @kutschkem 
for a simple game like this you want to have simple program structure, if there's no need for threading stay away from it (except if you want to practice thread handling, but that's another story). 
the answer seems reasonable, i'll add another answer with some performance tips